# Ubuntu 18.04. stuck at purple screen

Tags: graphics

Sorry for this question because I know it's being asked a lot but I couldn't find a solution in other posts so far. I installed Ubuntu and since the first boot I always end up with the system showing a purple screen and that's it. I guess that this has to do with my AMD graphics card. It's an AMD Radeon HD 7850. I searched through the questions here and managed to start the system with editing the line starting with linux to "nomodeset" in the grub menu. I tried to install AMD proprietary drivers but that didn't fix the problem either. I'm all new to Ubuntu and not being able to fix this problem even after days of research is frustrating me a lot. Maybe any of you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, do not try to install drivers but instead make sure all updates are installed. Reboot normally to test.

Comment: How do I make sure that all updates are installed? I started the system and clicked update in settings but it said, that there are none available.

Comment: For good measure, in terminal, `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks @GabrielaGarcia that worked! But still when I boot the system I don't see the login screen although it's there. I can blindly type in my login data and press enter but I don't see anything. Just the purple screen. And do you know how I can remove the AMD drivers I just installed?

Comment: If it's (partially) working as it seems to be now it perhaps not a good idea to mess with it. But, if you want, I think the instructions to remove are the same with a different parameter? Like --remove or --uninstall...